# Connected IP in failover ActiveMq c#

Tags: c#, .net, activemq-classic

I have this uri

```
string address = "failover:(tcp://10.127.31.6:5616,tcp://10.128.22.31.5:5616,tcp://10.129.22.33.5)?randomize=false";

_connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(address);
```

The failover works fine but how can i know or find out at which ip i am connected in c# ?

Answer (score 0):

You must cast your Connection the the Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.Connection type, and then you have access to its Transport property.  From the Transport you can retrieve the remote URI via a property accessor.  Be aware though that since you are using failover this property can return null if not connected.

The IConnection interface defines event point for ConnectionInterripted and ConnectionResumed which would allow you to know when a connection is successfully made at which point you can check the transport for the remote URI of the connection.

Answer (score 0):

failover:(tcp://primary:61616,tcp://secondary:61616)?randomize=false

The Failover transport chooses a URI at random by default. This effectively load-balances clients over multiple brokers. However, to have a client connect to a primary first and only connect to a secondary backup broker when the primary is unavailable, set randomize=false.